A weird tangent and cotangent integral by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.
From Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, there's a formula that states for $a>0$ and $b>0$:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\tan(ax)}{x^2+b^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{e^{2ab}+1}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cot(ax)}{x^2+b^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{e^{2ab}-1}.$$
However, according to WolframAlpha these integrals diverge.
Are these formulas actually true or is this a mistake?

Perhaps they meant the Cauchy principal value of the integral?

I also believe this was obtained via contour integration, but I could be wrong

The integrals are versions of those in Bateman Manuscript "Integral Tranforms vol 1" near page 81. There it is indicated that the integrals are principal values, a comment that did not make into Gradshteyn.

Gradshteyn and Ryzhik cite Gröbner and Hofreiter's Integraltafel, 2. Teil, Bestimmte Integrale, formula 333.79a. This formula is written with a sign that looks like a $\int!!!!\mathsf c$ (a letter C set into an integral sign), which I'd take to mean the Cauchy principal value.

OHHHHH, that makes a lot of sense now. I probably didnt see the letter c or any labels of PV.

I'm not surprised, since Gradshteyn and Ryzhik just write it as an ordinary integral without any extra notation.

Those integrals don’t converge in Riemann sense as there is a lot of discontinuities, however, it converges in some other sense. Look at the graph of $\frac{x\tan x}{x^2+1}$:

It seems that if you cut the integral into a lot of pieces, each piece has a length of $\boldsymbol\pi$, the area seems to get smaller and smaller. You can make sense of it this way:
$$\text{Take }\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x\tan ax}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x.$$
The graph as $a$ varies:

You may notice that the integral goes to infinity as $a$ goes to $\frac{1}{2}$. But what’s after that? The value of the integral for $ a>\frac{1}{2}$ is the analytic continuation.
Take an example:
$$\qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}\text{ for $|x|<1$}$$
Analytic continuation is essentially saying that: we don’t care about the conditions and plug in $ x=2$, therefore $1+2+4+… “=” -1$
By a similar logic, we can find an analytic function representing $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x\tan ax}{x^2+b^2}\mathrm{d}x$, then we could “plug in $a$ regardless” and get a value. You can do the same thing to $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$, $\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}$, and so on. As every piece of integral will converge for some sufficiently small $a$, there is always a way to find an analytic function to represent a corresponding piece, you can substitute $\boldsymbol a$ value for each piece, add them up, and say that is the value of $\boldsymbol{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\tan ax}{x^2+b^2}}$dx
In summary, both answers are correct. Just like the sum of all natural numbers, you can say it diverges to infinity, while you can also argue that it is $\zeta(-1)$ which equals to $-\frac{1}{12}$.

$\zeta(-1)=-1$. Last week it was $-1/12$. When did it change?

@OscarLanzi fixed. thx

We can compute these integrals directly.
Consider two convergent integrals:
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(\cos^2 ax)}{x^2+b^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{b}\ln \frac{\cosh (ab)}{e^{ab}}$$
$$J=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(\sin^2 ax)}{x^2+b^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{b}\ln \frac{\sinh (ab)}{e^{ab}}$$
By differentiating these integrals with respect to $a$, we get the integrals given in the original post.
